# Microsoft Bot Framework WebChat (DirectLine) causing Postback on AJAX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I am following the steps as detailed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat to implement Microsoft Bot Framework (in C# SDK). I have tested it on a standalone page and it is working fine. I require to use the DirectLine version as I have to pass values from webpage to the bot (for user initalization).

However, the page where I have to implement this is an ASP.NET WebForms (using ScriptManager and AJAXToolkit).

The issue arises when using the bot. By typing any content in the chat window and pressing enter, the whole page refreshes and the bot reinitailizes to start. This makes the bot unusable.

I am guessing that the chat control's "Send" button is somehow triggering a postback via ScriptManager causing the whole page to refresh. I had to include e.preventDefault() on the click event of the button that shows the chat window to take care of this situation. I am lost when it comes to within the Directline chat control.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use [FormFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow) instead of a web form?

Comment: Another option would be to put your form in an [Adaptive card](http://adaptivecards.io/) take a look at the [input sample](http://adaptivecards.io/samples/Inputs.html) it is probably a good starting point for what you need to accomplish if you do choose to go this route

Comment: @JasonSowers The bot is already built using Dialogs... Need that flexibility...

Comment: Hi @Chints, any updates? do you try to put it inside UpdatePanel control? does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

> The issue arises when using the bot. By typing any content in the chat window and pressing enter, the whole page refreshes and the bot reinitailizes to start. This makes the bot unusable.

I have same issue when I embed my bot in webform page (.aspx), to solve this problem, I put the chat bot container `<div id="mybot" />` inside **UpdatePanel** control and set **ChildrenAsTriggers** property to **false**, which works for me, you can try it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="mybot" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: 'directline_secret_here' },
        user: { id: '1234', firstname: 'firstname_here', lastname: 'lastname_here' },
        bot: { id: 'fehantestbot' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("mybot"))
</script>
```

**Screenshot of my test:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.. However this didn't solve my issue.. Even with this, I am constantly getting a postback :(

Comment: Can you edit your question to share your relevant code? It will help reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to build this into a DNN module.
Prevented it by inserting e.preventDefault to onKeyPress function in the Shell.tsx file in the BotFramework-WebChat project, and rebuilding it.

[BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-webchat)\src\Shell.tsx:

```js
//...
    private onKeyPress(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) { 
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {   
            e.preventDefault();  //new line: prevent page reload
            this.sendMessage();
        }
    }
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to prevent page refresh while sending chat from direclineJS webchat:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```